# Folder default ACLs not inherited when new file is created

Tags: unix, filesystems, access-control-list, cygwin

I'm a bit of a beginner with Unix systems, but I'm running Cygwin on my Windows Server, and I am trying to figure out something related to extended ACLs.

I have a directory to which I set the following ACLs:

```
Administrator@MyServer ~
$ setfacl -m d:u:Someuser:r-- somedir

Administrator@MyServer ~
$ getfacl somedir/
# file: somedir/
# owner: Administrator
# group: None
user::rwx
group::r-x
mask:rwx
other:r-x
default:user::rwx
default:user:Someuser:r--
default:group::r-x
default:mask:rwx
default:other:r-x
```

As you can see mose of the `default` ACLs have the x bit. Then when I create a fine in it, it doesn't inherit the ACLs it is supposed to:

```
Administrator@MyServer ~
$ touch somedir/somefile

Administrator@MyServer ~
$ getfacl somedir/somefile
# file: somedir/somefile
# owner: Administrator
# group: None
user::rw-
user:Someuser:r--
group::r--
mask:rwx
other:r--
```

It's basically missing the x bit everywhere.

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doc in http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#setfacl says :

> Limitations: Under Cygwin, the default ACL entries are not taken into account currently.

Note that `somedir/somefile` is also missing the default ACLs which it should have inherited.

Comment: Files don't get default ACLs.